# How do i calculate the rotation of a vector field only using the definition of rotation, without any coordinates?

Tags: differential-topology

Given any  vector field , how do i either: calculate the rotation using vector calculus definition, use the differential forms definition of rotation and use differential geometry to show at leat that the vector field is integrable( has zero rotation). 
Example : 1.constant gravitational vector field g

```
               2. A vector field that is written in component form: v=3y in epsilon direction + 2x in y direction
```

They key is , no mater what vector field i have , can i interpret in a way to calculate the rotation without any coordinates?

Comment: I am confused by what you mean by vector calculus definitoin: If you are using the curl, this is a coordinate dependent notion.

Comment: If youre confused about vector calculus definition, the alternitive is differential forms definition. Vector calculus also has a coordinate independent definition.